# Python remove blank spaces in output with integers

Tags: python, integer, number-formatting, python-3.8

I'm looking for a solution for this, searched and tried several ones, but none working with int datatypes, using python 3.8.5.

```
begin = 1
end = 273
print ("lines:", begin, "-", end)
```

result:

```
lines: 1 - 273
```

needed:

```
lines: 1-273
```

What do I need to do to remove the blank spaces using string and integer variables?

Thx

Comment: by default print add a space between elements, you can do `print ("lines: ", begin, "-", chunk1_end, sep="")` or create the string to print / use formatting etc. I encourage you to read python doc to save time rather than to ask that kind of question here ...

Comment: @ChrisCharley *begin* and *chunk1_end* are int so `begin + "-" +  chunk1_end`must be `str(begin) + "-" +  str(chunk1_end)` ;-)

Comment: begin + "-" +  chunk1_end errors out with TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: print ("lines:", str(begin) + "-" + str(end)) works, thx 4 that!

Answer (score 3):

You can use f strings, introduced in python 3.6.

```
begin = 1
end = 273
print(f"lines: {begin}-{end}")
```

Answer (score 2):

try this line it's better

```
print(f"lines: {begin}-{chunk1_end}")
```

also makes your code readable and more controllable

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `,` you can use `+`

```
begin = 1
end = 273
print ("lines:", str(begin)+"-"+str(chunk1_end))
```

or you can use `str.format()`

```
begin = 1
end = 273
print ("lines: {}-{}".format(begin, chunk1_end))
```